# x86 or x64 of VTK and Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, vtk

Could someone kindly shed light on the selection of the installation of `QT`/`VTK`  `x86` or `x64`? I would like to create a GUI by `QT` with `VTK` integration for 3D medical imaging visualization. What are the main criteria for choosing between `x86` and `x64`? For example, I know that the need for addressing an array which requires more than 4GB forces to use `x64` architecture. Is there other criteria? For example, when it comes to distributing the GUI among others, is there something that determine the suitability of `x86` or `x64`. Can I install `QT` `x86` along with `VTK` `x64`? I would love to have the community's opinion on this.

Comment: For the last 5 or so years I build vtk and Qt under windows I build 64 bit versions since all of the target machines are 64 bit and with 0.625 mm slices in lung CT does not take too much to use more than the 2GB of user address space you get with a 32 bit application ( without the usage of LARGEADDRESSAWARE).

Comment: Thanks. What would you recommend for the compiler for Windows? Visual Studio? If so, what version? May I also know what versions of Qt and VTK you use? I've heard it is very challenging to successfully install all these tools to work perfectly together. For example, having QVTKWidget.

Comment: I use develop using Visual Studio 2010 however in a totally separate build tree I build my releases in Visual Studio 2013. I create a separate binary tree for each compiler that I target. I use cmake out of source building so my sources are in x:/CMakeBased/Qt/LungAnalysis.. And my binaries are in x:/x64/VS.100/Qt/LungAnalysis and  x:/x64/VS.120/Qt/LungAnalysis. Inside of the x64/VS.100/ i have my libraries like Qt built at  x64/VS.100/Libraries/Qt-4.8.X  x64/VS.100/Libraries/vtk-5.10.X with a similar tree in x64/VS.120.

Comment: I am using older versions of vtk and Qt because internal libraries that I use for my display use vtk setInput() functions instead of setInputConnection() and I have not spent the weeks to months to rewrite this code. If I was starting fresh I would checkout the latest vtk and Qt-5.3+.

Comment: @drescherjm: thanks. Would you share with me some working instructions in order to successfully use VTK and Qt in Visual Studio? I have failed several times following the tips that I have found online. Do you use Qt 4.8 and VTK 6.0?

Comment: No I am using vtk-5.10 for reasons in my last post. My one recommendation is to avoid building shared libraries for any Kitware software. And also never ever use the install target. The reason for that is if you install a debug build you must never compile your release build against that. Instead of the INSTALL target I point VTK_DIR to the root of the vtk build folder when I configure my applications that use vtk. I use cmake to generate the projects for all of my own applications. With this method I can compile and execute against all 3 configurations (Release, RelWithDebInfo and Debug).

Comment: I have to go for now. Its 10:45PM here on the east coast of the US and I am worn out..